# How to represent passing of time?

Tags: java, javafx, simulation

I'm creating a simple simulation of gas station as homework. The total duration of the simulation is the week. Filling cars is approximately 3 minutes depending on the type of fuel. Cars may be collected in a queue. Now the question. I know how to implement these methods, but have no idea how to simulate a period of time without methods like a `Thread.sleep()`.

P.S. I'm using JavaFX framework for this task. Cars are represented as `javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle` and their movements through `Tranlsate` methods. Dispensers too.

Comment: It seems like you need some sort of loop that constantly updates the position and state of the various objects. This way you control how fast time goes. Yet, this loop needs something like Thread.sleep, otherwise it will max out your cpu quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Thread.sleep()` method accepts a millisecond value. Basically, you can run an update and then calculate how long you need to sleep until the next update.

You can measure real time elapsed with `System.nanoTime()`. Make sure your class `implements Runnable`. Inside the run method, stick a while loop which contains an `update()` method to update the cars. Get nano time at the start and end of the loop, subtracting the two which gives you elapsed time. Subtract the elapsed time from the time you want each update to take, then sleep the thread. I think that is really all you need.

Here is the code:

```
public void run() {
    int updatesPerSecond = 5;
    /* The target time is the time each update should take.
     * You want the target time to be in milliseconds.
     * so 5 updates a second is 1000/5 milliseconds. */
    int targetTime = 1000 / updatesPerSecond;
    long currentTime;
    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    long elapsedTime;
    long sleepTime;

    while (running) {

        // get current time (in nanoseconds)
        currentTime = System.nanoTime();

        // get time elapsed since last update
        elapsedTime = currentTime - lastTime;
        lastTime = currentTime;

        // run your update
        update();

        // compute the thread sleep time in milliseconds.
        // elapsed time is converted to milliseconds.
        sleepTime = targetTime - (elapsedTime / 1000000000);

        // don't let sleepTime drop below 0
        if (sleepTime < 0) {
            sleepTime = 1;
        }

        // attempt to sleep
        try {
            Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Within JavaFX framework,
you can simply use [PauseTransition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/PauseTransition.html) to simulate periodic time elapsing. On end of every period update scene graph elements' states. If you are going to change some properties of some node and do various animations you may utilize other [types of Transitions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Transition.html). For more fine grained control you can use [Timeline](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Timeline.html) with its [KeyFrame](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/KeyFrame.html)s.